# Android emulator: changing soft keyboard language

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I want to change my Android emulator soft keyboard language. So far, I have a Japanese layout and I tried a lot of things unsuccessfully. I want to have an English (or whatsoever western Latin) layout. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long Press on the key shown below

[image: Capture 1]

It will show the following menu

[image]

select the appropriate keyboard type and language it will show that keyboard

[image]