# Strange keyboard on my virtual machine

Tags: android

i decided to try testing my app on the virtual device instead of the phone and here is what I encountered when I clicked an edittext. How do I change this to a qwerty keyboard in a normal language?

[image]

here are the settings of my vd

[image]

[image]

I cant find an option to disable japanese ime:

[image]

Comment: What are exactly the settings of your virtual android device ?
Did you try to go to Settings and change Language/input ?

Comment: did you try with this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14929978/1748764

Comment: yay. that helped me switch to qwerty but the chinese symbols are still here :(

Comment: Is possible disable JAPANESE IME in the settings?

Comment: I dont know how. long press doesnt do anything and I've attached an image of what is inside of that menu in my updated question

Comment: @jackgris have you seen it

Comment: And the setting in android keyboard, in the input languages?

Comment: With target Android 2.2 you have choice for check and uncheck Japanese IME and Android Keyboard http://androidbite.blogspot.com.ar/2012/11/how-to-disable-japanese-chinese.html

Comment: but there is no checkbox to the right of the Japanese and Chinese stuff, as I've pointed out in the screenshot :( @jackgris

Comment: I know, but if you try with change the """input languages""" on the "Android Keyboard",or if you use other version of Android Emulator? Why you need only Android 2.3.3?